# Running openni_camera and an additional external USB camera

Tags: kinect, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been having issues when running simultaneously both the Kinect's camera and a secondary (external) USB camera. I have successfully run several cameras together (different drivers and flavors). I am also able to run a kinect without RGB depth registration (so the RGB camera is off) plus other external cameras. However, I can't seem to be able to run both the Kinect RGB camera and an additional USB camera.

Has anyone been successful with this setup: Kinect with RGB registration + Secondary USB camera?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36548/running-openni_camera-and-an-additional-external-usb-camera/) by [ubuntuslave](https://answers.ros.org/users/631/ubuntuslave/) on ROS Answers with karma: 347 on 2012-06-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would gess that this is caused by the high data amount of both devices. The Data is to much for one single USB-Bus (not ports).
Try to check which bus the devices are connectet to by `$lsusb` .
Then simply try to connect the devices to different buses. Another idea would be that the webcam is claiming the hole bandwith of to USB-port. Webcams request a whole load of bandwidth, usually more than they need.
The uvcvideo kernel module can be set to ignore the requested bandwidth, and to calculate the right bandwidth. Try:

```
$sudo rmmod uvcvideo
$sudo modprobe uvcvideo quirks=128
```

This will be reset every reboot. If this works, create the following file:

```
$sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/uvcvideo.conf
```

containing the line:

```
options uvcvideo quirks=128
```

*reference:*
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.drivers.uvc.devel/5510

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-kernel-70/facecam-312-kernel-10-10-conflagration-help-853934/

---

Originally posted by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) with karma: 447 on 2012-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ubuntuslave](https://answers.ros.org/users/631/ubuntuslave/) on 2012-06-15**:
Thanks, the "lsusb" command helped me realize my computer(s) had  only 1 USB bus shared among the hubs (even when appearing to be physical apart). The quirks setting did help me with low resolution video and multiple UVC cameras, but still don't know which "mod probe" module applies to the kinect.